# Is there a possible way to create screenshots of the whole screen out of a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, screenshot

I'm currently creating screenshots with JavaScript using canvas and encoding them in base64.

However, my current screenshots only include the actual web page and nothing else (no address bar, etc.) and I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve a screenshot of the whole screen (taskbar, and the whole browser window, etc.) programmatically.

Comment: I think not, and it shouldn't be, it is very insecure. Do you imagine that after enter a site They are gathering information about your running programs (analyzing taskbar) etc ?

Comment: I may need to give you some little more information about what I intend to do. My company has it's own, "re"programed, firefox browser and I'm creating an extension for this. My extension sends a request to a monitor server if a website opened by that browser responds with a configured statuscode(e.g. 404, 500). Additionally to that, I'm supposed to send a screenshot with the error, that works well, but my company would like to see the whole browser window and not just the website. (I don't know the reasons and the current version will do for now, but I wanted to know if it'd be possible^^)

Comment: Maybe if browser support's it but i doubt it but can't tell for sure

Comment: Me too, but I was curious if it weren't possible at all. I guess they just have to be happy with the page itself. Thanks thought, for your try.

Comment: out of intrest. Have been playing with canvas/encoding lately myself. But your usage sounds interesting (screendump). If you want to share code or links of interest....please do.

Comment: Here you go: http://snipt.org/uhhz7

But you've to encode it afterwards. Hope it'll help you. :)

Comment: A firefox add-on should be allowed to do what it wants (restricted by the OS maybe). But exposing that api to the website (through Javascript or something) is a security hole.

Comment: What do you mean by that Bergi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have this functionality. The best you can do is using operating system functions via [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes). However, it isn't quite simple. I needed this code for the Windows API anyway so here it comes. First you need to set up the libraries, functions and data types:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");

var userlib = ctypes.open("user32");
var gdilib = ctypes.open("gdi32");

var HWND = ctypes.voidptr_t;
var HGDIOBJ = ctypes.voidptr_t;
var HDC = HGDIOBJ;
var HBITMAP = HGDIOBJ;
var LPCTSTR = ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr;
var WORD = ctypes.uint16_t;
var DWORD = ctypes.uint32_t;

var SRCCOPY = 0xCC0020;

var BITMAPCOREHEADER = ctypes.StructType("BITMAPCOREHEADER", [
  {bcSize: DWORD},
  {bcWidth: WORD},
  {bcHeight: WORD},
  {bcPlanes: WORD},
  {bcBitCount: WORD}
]);

var GetDC = userlib.declare(
  "GetDC", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  HDC,
  HWND
);

var ReleaseDC = userlib.declare(
  "ReleaseDC", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.int,
  HWND, HDC
);

var CreateCompatibleDC = gdilib.declare(
  "CreateCompatibleDC", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  HDC,
  HDC
);

var CreateCompatibleBitmap = gdilib.declare(
  "CreateCompatibleBitmap", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  HBITMAP,
  HDC, ctypes.int, ctypes.int
);

var DeleteObject = gdilib.declare(
  "DeleteObject", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.bool,
  HGDIOBJ
);

var SelectObject = gdilib.declare(
  "SelectObject", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  HGDIOBJ,
  HDC, HGDIOBJ
);

var BitBlt = gdilib.declare(
  "BitBlt", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.bool,
  HDC, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.int,
  HDC, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, DWORD
);

var GetDIBits = gdilib.declare(
  "GetDIBits", ctypes.winapi_abi,
  ctypes.int,
  HDC, HBITMAP, ctypes.unsigned_int, ctypes.unsigned_int,
  ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr, BITMAPCOREHEADER.ptr, ctypes.unsigned_int
);
```

And now the interesting part:

```js
// The screen part we want to copy
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height;

// Create a bitmap/device context for the data
var screenDC = GetDC(null);
var dc = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
var bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, width, height);

// Copy screen contents to bitmap
SelectObject(dc, bitmap);
BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, width, height, screenDC, x, y, SRCCOPY);

// Extract bitmap data
var bitmapHeader = new BITMAPCOREHEADER();
bitmapHeader.bcSize = BITMAPCOREHEADER.size;
bitmapHeader.bcWidth = width;
bitmapHeader.bcHeight = height;
bitmapHeader.bcPlanes = 1;
bitmapHeader.bcBitCount = 32;

var dataSize = width * height * 4;
var buffer = new ctypes.ArrayType(ctypes.unsigned_char, dataSize)();
GetDIBits(dc, bitmap, 0, height, buffer, bitmapHeader.address(), 0);

// Clean up
ReleaseDC(null, screenDC);
DeleteObject(dc);
DeleteObject(bitmap);

userlib.close();
gdilib.close();

// Draw data to the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width", width);
canvas.setAttribute("height", height);

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
  // Windows bitmaps are stored bottom-to-top, they are also using BGR0
  // byte order instead of RGBA. The data needs to be corrected here.
  var offset1 = i * width * 4;
  var offset2 = (height - 1 - i) * width * 4;
  for (var j = 0; j < width; j++)
  {
    imageData.data[offset1 + j * 4 + 0] = buffer[offset2 + j * 4 + 2];
    imageData.data[offset1 + j * 4 + 1] = buffer[offset2 + j * 4 + 1];
    imageData.data[offset1 + j * 4 + 2] = buffer[offset2 + j * 4 + 0];
    imageData.data[offset1 + j * 4 + 3] = 255;
  }
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

For other operating systems you would need entirely different code of course. The alternative would be packaging a specialized DLL with your extension and using it via js-ctypes - this would allow writing the same thing in C++, that would be slightly simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for that code! I've got one question thought:
I read (at developer.mozilla.org) that the js-cytpes lib is only available since Gecko 2.0 (FF 4.0). Our browser is based on FF 3.6...
I guess i have to code the whole thing in c++ then.

Comment: @Termi: js-ctypes in Firefox 3.6 is very limited, it was an experimental feature back then - it can only work with simple types, not even pointers are possible. So yes, either write the whole thing in C++ (a regular DLL that you can call via js-ctypes without any complicated parameters or an XPCOM component) or update your browser to a less outdated Gecko version.

Comment: Tanks, I'll have to stick to c++ than. As I mentioned above, the browser is from my company and wont be updated to a newer version very soon...

Answer (score 0):

no - security like stated by the comments.

only thing you can do is to is to get what ever you need/can get from the document info (like location.href). Add that as visible information in bottom/top => grap => hide again (if user should continue working).

Comment: This question is about a Firefox extension - security doesn't play a role.

Answer (score -1):

**first press `shift+F2`**
it opens firefox console..give command `screenshot --fullpage` and press enter(For fullpage)

`screenshot`(For only the visible part)

you also can do this by going to **tools->web developer->developer toolbar**

Its worth take a try..its best without a extension

Comment: First of all, the question is about 15 months old. Secondly, your solution has nothing to do with the problem at hand, at that time I needed to create a screenshot **out of an extension** programatically in Firefox 3.6. Doing it manually (meaning that the customer had to do this, which did not have access on the console) was not an option.

Comment: sorry @Termi i thought it would help other users in future..hence i put my ans..though i did not notice ur question thoroughly...sorry for that again..never mind